# Can you make electricity from the bound charges in magnets?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, magnetic-monopoles

Magnetostatics is the study of magnetic fields in systems where the currents are steady. If inside magnets that give off magnetic fields there are bound charges, is there any possible way to make them free charges and therefore get electricity from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if inside magnets ... there are bound charges, is there any possible way to make them freee charges and therefore get electrity from them?

Hardly.

Let us see, how permanent magnets could be made. You use materials which obey a strong magnetic dipole moment, melt the material to powder and press [(sinter)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet#Composites) the powder under the influence of a strong external magnetic field to a rigid body.

What happens in detail?

> > The overall magnetic behavior of a material can vary widely, depending on the structure of the material, particularly on its electron configuration. [(Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet#Magnetic_materials)

Under the electron configuration you have to understand the sum of the magnetic dipole moments of the involved subatomic particles. Usually the are oriented in all directions. Under the influence of the external magnetic field they get aligned. This happens mostly by rotation into the aligned direction. No electric current is involved.

To destroy the alignment you may drop the magnet but this is not recommended because you can injure yourself. Or you heat the magnet and at some moment the increasing vibrations on the atomic level destroy the magnetization. But hardly any electric current will occur.

Comment: The search for such a machine has been going on for at least a hundred years; the technical reasons why devices of this type- which are often referred to as "magnetic motors"- cannot ever be built are available on line, on sites which debunk so-called "free energy" devices.

Comment: @user40292 Maybe you want to tell me something different about a “magnetic motor”, but [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/361600/electric-charge-attraction-unlike-magnet-attraction-can-be-neutralized-right/361638#361638) is one :-)

Comment: no, what I meant is this: there are characteristics of a vector field that are called the curl and the divergence. The values of the curl and divergence of a magnetic field are such as to prohibit anyone from ever being able to make a motor which is powered by permanent magnets alone, a fact which was proved mathematically a long time ago.